# Slick-center not working when number of slides is a not a multiple of 3 or less than six with slidesToScroll = 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, slick.js

I have given some margin top to my slick-center class.I want the slick slider to scroll 3 slides at once.These are my slider settings :

```
$(".center").slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
  });

 $(".center").slick('slickSetOption', 'slidesToScroll', 3, true);
});
```

As slidesToScroll does not work with centerMode ,I'm using slickSetOption to force it to work with scrolling three slides at once.

The issue: This slick-center styling works perfectly fine when the number of slides in my slider are in multiples of 3.But whenever the number of slides are 4,5 .. or any non three multiple,the slick slider doesn't append the correct slide with the slick-center class.

This is my codepen :- https://codepen.io/shivanit2/pen/zLwzbR 
Currently there are 8 slides in my codepen,and you can see how its not giving the correct styling .(if you scroll on the third slick-dot)
If you increase 1 slide,it will work perfectly.(multiple of 3's)

How can I resolve this issue?